# Shopify Liquid and Ajax: Adding and Removing Products in Cart Based on Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify store and trying to implement a feature using Liquid and Ajax. I have a script that adds a free product to the cart when a qualifying product is present. Additionally, I want to remove the free product if the qualifying product is removed from the cart.

Here's the existing code I'm using:

```
<script>
  
  window.onload = function(){
    let cartContainsFreeProduct = false;
    let cartContainsQualifyingProduct = false;
 
    const qualifyingProductVariantId = ***ENTER VARIANT ID OF PRODUCT THAT QUALIFIES FOR FREE PRODUCT***; 
    const freeProductVariantId = ***ENTER VARIANT ID OF THE FREE PRODUCT***;
           
    {% for item in cart.items %}
      if({{ item.id }} === freeProductVariantId){
        cartContainsFreeProduct = true; 
      }
      if({{ item.id }} === qualifyingProductVariantId){
         cartContainsQualifyingProduct = true;
      }
    {% endfor %}
    
//  If cart contains qualifying product and doesn't already contain free product, add qty 1 of free product
    if(cartContainsQualifyingProduct && cartContainsFreeProduct === false) {
        
      jQuery.post('/cart/add.json', { quantity: 1, id: freeProductVariantId })
      .done(function() {window.location.reload()})    
        
     } 
  }
  
</script>
```

The script for adding the free product seems to be working fine but how do remove the product freeProductVariantId when removing the qualifyingProductVariantId from the cart